# multidimensional arrays(check if id exists in the nested array)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

im doing a ecommerce system. this is how the filled array look like:
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 (this is the id)
            [1] => 1 ((this is the quantity)
            [2] =>  abcd (this some kind of txt box)
            [3] => 10 (this is the price)
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 1
        [2] =>  efg
        [3] => 50
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] =>  bla bla bla
        [3] => 10
    )
```

now i need to check when inserting does the id exist,if it does just and quantity.
this is the code:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
            $array = $_SESSION['cart'];
            $item = array($_POST['id'], $_POST["quantity"], $_POST['txt'], $_POST['price']);
            array_push($array, $item);
            $_SESSION["cart"] = $array;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart"] = array(array($_POST['id'], $_POST["quantity"], $_POST['txt'], $_POST['price']));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 if (!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
        $item =array();
        $array = $_SESSION['cart'];
        if(!empty($_POST['id'])
         $item = array($_POST['id'], $_POST["quantity"], $_POST['txt'], $_POST['price']);
        array_push($array, $item);
        $_SESSION["cart"] = $array;  
    } else {
        $_SESSION["cart"] = array(array($_POST['id'], $_POST["quantity"], $_POST['txt'], $_POST['price']));
    }
```

Comment: [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] =>  prvi topli
            [3] => 10
        )

    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] =>  
            [3] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] =>  
            [3] => 10
it adds as a new array again